# Why are type parameters are not allowed on this type?

Tags: generics, macros, rust, type-inference

Attempting to compile the following,

```
fn do_it() -> Result<i32, u32> {
    Result::<i32, u32>::Ok(3)
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", do_it());
}
```

results in:

```
./result_test.rs:2:14: 2:17 error: type parameters are not allowed on this type [E0109]
./result_test.rs:2     Result::<i32, u32>::Ok(3)
                                ^~~
```

**Why are type parameters not allowed on this type?**

This is a minimal example, my real-world example is a macro trying to return the following:

```
match $reader.$read_func() {
    Ok(n) => Result::<$read_type, LocalReadError>::Ok(n),
    Err(err) => Result::<$read_type, LocalReadError>::Err(
        LocalReadError::from(err)
    ),
}
```

`$read_func` is a function, `$read_type` is the return type of that function. (If I had a programmatic way to get that, I'd do so; I don't know how, so it's an arg…); as-is, I get the above error. If I remove the specification of the generic's parameters, type inteference complains that it can't figure out the type. (Because it ends up with `Result<_, LocalReadError>` in one branch of the `match`, and `Result<$read_type, _>` in the other? I'm not really sure. It says:

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
    match $reader.$read_func() {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

)

*Note:* The question about why type parameters are not allowed is answered below. Turns out this is not the cause of the "unable to infer enough type information". (`read_func` is a function, in my case, I'm passing a templated function, but forgetting the template arg, which can't be inferred.)

Comment: That looks to me remarkably like a bug. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/error-index.html#E0109 shows what it’s supposed to be doing.

Comment: as a workaround to your actual problem I suggest to change your macro to `$reader.$read_func().map_err(LocalReadError::from)`

Comment: not sure if it's a bug or if this is actually expected, but the syntax that works seems to be: `Result::Ok::<i32, u32>(3)`. [Playpen](http://is.gd/xNUV9B)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is actually an inconsistency with enums that [was discussed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22486) but not considered important enough to block 1.0.

The working syntax to specify types is `Result::Ok::<i32, u32>(3)`.

An enum works like something between a type (that would go with the syntax you were trying to write) and a namespace (and namespaces don't accept type parameters).

To demonstrate how enums are like namespaces, you can write:

```
use std::result::Result::*;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Ok::<i32, u32>(3));
}
```

This namespacing aspect is a desirable property of enums, but moving type parameters where one would intuitively think they should be would make this type of code very awkward to write.